# Slider.Minimum property negative value issue

Tags: silverlight, xaml, styles, slider, silverlight-5.0

Probably I've got another unsolvable problem. In Silverlight XAML, I am unable to set by `Style` negative value for `Slider.Minimum` property. I mean, it is possible, but the results are unexpected. In WPF this does work normally.

```
<StackPanel Width="200" Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Slider" x:Key="style">
            <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="-10" />
            <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Value" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <!-- Here it is not working -->
    <Slider Style="{StaticResource style}"/>
    <!-- Here it works as expected, as it is not styled -->
    <Slider Minimum="-10" Maximum="10" Value="0" />
</StackPanel>
```

The result is like this:

[image]

But obviously both thumbs should be in the same position (in the middle of `Slider`).

In fact, it look's like the `Minimum` value (-10) **is** accepted, but then `Maximum` value becomes 0, and that is why the first slider has a thumb aligned to a right side (`Value` is 0 and `Maximum` is also 0).

Comment: The problem is not the property `Minimun` on Slider, but the property `Maximum`, cause the value set in the style does not get applied.

Comment: Yes, I wrote this at the end of my post, but it still occurs only with negative `Minimum`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `HorizontalTemplate` of the Slider. If you change the `Orientation` of the Slider to `Vertical` then the values defined in your style get applied as expected.

**Update:**
The Solution is to set the Orientation also in the style. Then it works as expected.

```
<Style TargetType="Slider" x:Key="style">
  <Setter Property="Minimum"
          Value="-10" />
  <Setter Property="Maximum"
          Value="10" />
  <Setter Property="Value"
          Value="0" />
  <Setter Property="Orientation"
          Value="Horizontal" />
 </Style>
```

Comment: Are you sure? Which designer do you use? I use Visual Studio 2010. Your proposal didn't change anything in my environment. But I noticed another stuff: if I apply manually `Maximum="10"` to a styled slider (`<Slider Maximum="10" Style="{StaticResource style}" />`), the `Thumb` puts itself in correct position, and then I remove this (`Maximum="10"`), the `Thumb` is not going back to the right side (stays in the middle) until I reload xaml in designer. What happens if you reload the designer with your solution? Does it still work?

Comment: @infografnet I´m using Visual Studio 2012.